# Chrome Syncing Old Data

Tags: google-chrome

I have not synced any of my Bookmarks to my Google Account in a year or so. If I sign-in to Chrome will it automatically sync and overwrite all the data i currently have with old the data on my Google Account and if so how can I work around it?

Answer (score 0):

*synching* is not *overwriting*.

Yes, it would sync, but that means it will *merge them together*, so you would end with the old *and* the new links. You can then delete from the list the old stuff if you don't want it anymore.

If you happen to have modified a link since the last sync a year ago, the newer one will prevail.